# XStream with xml and java object

Tags: java, xstream

I have two java classes....

```
public class Item {
    private int itemIndex;
    private String containerType;
    private Map<String, List<String>> contentType;
    private String status;
    private List<String> remark; 
    // their getters and setters
}
```

Please tell me how to convert Item object to xml and xml to Item object? I have used XStream jar for conversion. I need to store multiple Item (list of items) in xml. Please provide full coding in JAVA to add a new item with existing items (stored in xml).

Comment: So you used XStream, but where exactly? Show some code pal. This is not a code factory, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

[Sample code](http://x-stream.github.io/objectstream.html)

```
ObjectOutputStream out = xstream.createObjectOutputStream(someWriter);

out.writeObject(new Person("Joe", "Walnes"));
out.writeObject(new Person("Someone", "Else"));
out.writeObject("hello");
out.writeInt(12345);

out.close();
```